# Именованные Каналы (NamedPipe) C++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

Голову сломал думая, что не так и пришел к выводу, что вообще все не так, есть подозрения, что так делать нельзя.
Суть программы в том, что один поток производит вычисления, создает канал и отдает результат другому потоку, который после преобразований выводит данные на экран.

Вот главная функция, там все понятно. Создаем два потока, на их вход ничего не идет.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD dw; 
    HANDLE IDThread[2];

    IDThread[0]=CreateThread(NULL,0,MainTread,0, 0, &dw);
    IDThread[1]=CreateThread(NULL,0,MinorThread,0, 0, &dw);

    WaitForMultipleObjects(ThrCount,IDThread,TRUE,INFINITE);

system("pause>>void");

    return 0;
}
```

Далее, 1-ый поток. (Программу я упростил до ужаса, оставив самое основное).

```
DWORD WINAPI MainTread(LPVOID Insert)
{
wchar_t *PName = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\TransmitPipe";   //Имя канала
HANDLE hPipe;                                    //Экземпляр самого канала
BOOL Success;                         //Принимает значения возвращаемые функциями
DWORD byteCnt, byteWrt;               //Число байт которые надо записать в поток и счетчик байт реально записанных в канал.

char X[10];   //Будем передавать второму потоку этот чар
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {X[i]='9';}  //Заполним его девятками
X[i]='\0'                            //На всякий случай

//Самое интересное

hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(PName,
                        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |
                        PIPE_WAIT,PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,4096,4096,0,NULL); if(hPipe!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {std::cout<<"1) Pipe create is OK \n";} //Проверка. Если экземпляр не вернул неправильное значение значит канал создан. 1) - означает что поток 1ый.

Success = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL); //Ожидаем запроса на соединение с этим каналом
if(Success){std::cout<<"1) Connect is OK \n";} //Если результат 1, значит соединение прошло

Success = WriteFile(hPipe, X, byteCnt, &byteWrt, NULL); //Пишем наш Х в канал hPipe
if(Success){std::cout<<"1) Write is OK \n";} //Функция вернула 1 - все ОК
}
```

Далее второй поток (Там в сообщениях вывода на экран будет "2)" ).

```
DWORD WINAPI MinorThread(LPVOID Insert)
{
wchar_t *PName = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\TransmitPipe";  //Все так же, это имя канала
HANDLE hPipe;                                   //Экземпляр
BOOL Success;
DWORD pMode;   //Это указатель на режим работы, подробнее ниже.

char X[10]; //Сюда пишем, то что пришлет канал

hPipe = CreateFile(PName,GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL); //Подключение к существующему каналу (созданному в 1ом потоке) 
if(hPipe!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {std::cout<<"2) File create is OK \n";} //Проверка (тот же смысл что и в 1П)

Success = WaitNamedPipe(PName, NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER); //Ожидание подключения к экземпляру канала
if(Success){std::cout<<"2) Pipe avelible OK \n";}    //Канал доступен если все нормально

pMode = PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE; //Режим чтения сообщений

Success = SetNamedPipeHandleState(hPipe, &pMode, NULL, NULL); //Переключение канала в режим чтения сообщений
if(Success){std::cout<<"2) Readmode is OK \n";}

Success = ReadFile(hPipe, Х, 4096, &byteWrt, NULL); //Чтение из экземпляра в Х. 4096 - размер буфера под читаемое сообщение
if(Success){std::cout<<"2) Read is OK \n";}

std::cout<<X;
}
```

Выводит 0.

А вот что пишет:

[image]

То есть канал создается и туда пишутся данные и даже второй поток к нему подключается, на этом вобщем то все и перестает работать.

Ну и вопрос: Хорошей идеей было кидать канал от потока к потоку? Может быть вы знаете где я накосячил в коде?

---

Поставил семафоры. Второй поток пытается читать из канала:
[image]

Суть ошибки: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
ERROR_NOACCESS
998 (0x3E6)
Invalid access to memory location.
```

Вопрос: Почему? Запись в канал идет нормально, почему ошибка при чтении, да еще и с жалобой на участок памяти.

Comment: @alexlz В ответе коментить не могу=( Спасибо, теперь ясно почему с памятью проблемы)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использование пайпов для передачи данных внутри одного процесса -- дичайший оверкилл, хуже было бы разве что использовать сокеты.

Для передачи данных из потока в поток используйте разделяемую структуру данных (например, std::queue), защищая её от одновременного доступа при помощи мьютекса (например, CRITICAL_SECTION, если хотите Windows-specific, или лучше [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), если ваш компилятор поддерживает стандарт C++11).

Вам нужен на самом деле паттерн [Producer-Consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).

Добро пожаловать во Вселенную многопоточного программирования!

---

По поводу вашего кода -- может, читающий поток ожидает, когда наконец в пайп попадут 4096 байт данных? Попробуйте в качестве отладки читать по одному байту.

Comment: Спасибо) я так и думал, смотря на то как печален результат работу, но увы данная программа - была не моя идея...

Comment: @BlackOverlord: смотрите в обновление ответа, так про пайпы

Comment: Прочитал про семафоры, щяс попробую)

Comment: @BlackOverlord: о! семафоры мегарулез! хотя я бы использовал condition variable.

Comment: Помогло) Стадия чтения идет, но с ошибкой, но это уже другая история. Щя подкоректирую.

Comment: Вот ведь странно, он не хочет писать в `char[100]`! Исправил на `char *X = new char[100]` и заработало!

Comment: Ну в вопросе нет в MainThread установки byteCnt для записи (видимо это уже исправлено). А вот длина буфера для чтения lpNumberOfBytesToRead в ReadFile не должна быть больше размера самого буфера X (иначе возможны проблемы с памятью)